# Dynamically push arrays into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to dynamically build an array for the Facebook Messenger SDK and populate it with data from a database.

I can't seem to get a properly structured array no matter what I try.

What I need:

```
        $messages = [
            "attachment" => [
                "type" => "template",
                "payload" => [
                    "template_type" => "generic",
                    "elements" => [[
                        "title" => $row['title'],
                        "item_url" => $row['item_url'],
                        "image_url" => $row['image_url'],
                        "subtitle" => $row['subtitle'],
                        "buttons" => [[
                        "type" => "web_url",
                        "url" => "www.google.com",
                        "title" => "View Website"],
                        ["type" => "postback",
                            "title" => "Start Chatting",
                            "payload" => "start"]]
                    ]
                ]]
            ]];
```

I need to create the data inside `buttons` based on what I have in the database, tried with `array_merge` and inserting the array as a string:

```
        // Created arrays
        if (!empty($row['button1_type'])) {
            $buttons[] = array("type" => $row['button1_type'],"url" => $row['button1_url'],
                "title" => $row['button1_title'],
                "payload" => $row['button1_payload']);
        }
        if (!empty($row['button2_type'])) {
            $buttons[] = array("type" => $row['button2_type'],"url" => $row['button2_url'],
                "title" => $row['button2_title'],
                "payload" => $row['button2_payload']);
        }

        // In the case when I had array_merge - $buttons were actually named as $buttons1 and $buttons2
        $buttons = array_merge($buttons1, $buttons2);

        // Tried to add it as a string
        if (!empty($row['button2_type'])) {
            $buttons = "\"type\" => ".$row['button2_type'].",\"url\" => .".$row['button2_url'].",
                \"title\" => ".$row['button2_title'].",
                \"payload\" => ".$row['button2_payload'];
        }

        $messages = [
            "attachment" => [
                "type" => "template",
                "payload" => [
                    "template_type" => "generic",
                    "elements" => [[
                        "title" => $row['title'],
                        "item_url" => $row['item_url'],
                        "image_url" => $row['image_url'],
                        "subtitle" => $row['subtitle'],
                        "buttons" => [
                            $buttons
                        ]
                    ]
                ]]
            ]];
```

Screenshot showing the differences between correct and incorrect:
[image]

So basically `$buttons` are created inside an extra array, how can I get rid of it? Maybe I should change the whole approach?

Comment: use `"buttons" => $buttons` ?

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks, it's working now.

Comment: i am glad that i could help, happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
"buttons" => [$buttons]
//new array  ^        ^
```

a new array is being created with square brackets so to avoid it. use

```
"buttons" => $buttons
```